# Initial ERC20 Token supply split into 2 or more hardcoded addresses

Tags: solidity, tokens, erc-20, addresses

don't know if someone can help me, but let me explain my problem.
For more transparency in my ERC20 token generation smart contract, I want to hardcode the Team Pool (0xA) and Crowdfunding Pool (0xB) with allocation amounts, just as example.

```
constructor() public {
    symbol = "STT";
    name = "Sample Token";
    decimals = 18; 

    totalSupply_ = 500000000 * (10 ** uint256(decimals));
    // Now we need to split the total supply into 2 hardcoded addresses
}

//my pseudo code idea 
function allocate() public {
    allocations[0xAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA] = 250000000 * (10 ** uint256(decimals));
    allocations[0xBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB] = 250000000 * (10 ** uint256(decimals)); 
}
```

Means that after deployment the total supply will be distributed to two ethereum addresses.

Can someone guide me, please and how the amounts are send while deployment. ? 
The rest of the code is based on https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity BasicToken without mint or burn

Thanks in advance

Cheers

```
contract SampleToken is PausableToken {
    string public constant name = "Sample Token"; 
    string public constant symbol = "STT";
    uint256 public constant decimals = 18;

    mapping (address => uint256) freezes;

    /* This notifies clients about the amount burnt */
    event Burn(address indexed from, uint256 value);

    /* This notifies clients about the amount frozen */
    event Freeze(address indexed from, uint256 value);

    /* This notifies clients about the amount unfrozen */
    event Unfreeze(address indexed from, uint256 value);

    constructor() public {
        totalSupply_ = 500000000 * (10 ** uint256(decimals));
        balances[msg.sender] = totalSupply_;
        // we need to split the total supply to two or more addresses 
    }

    function freezeOf(address _owner) public view returns (uint256) {
        return freezes[_owner];
    }

    function burn(uint256 _value) whenNotPaused public returns (bool) {
        require(_value <= balances[msg.sender]);

        balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].sub(_value);
        totalSupply_ = totalSupply_.sub(_value);
        emit Burn(msg.sender, _value);
        return true;
    }

    function freeze(uint256 _value) whenNotPaused public returns (bool) {
        require(_value <= balances[msg.sender]);

        balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].sub(_value);
        freezes[msg.sender] = freezes[msg.sender].add(_value);
        emit Freeze(msg.sender, _value);
        return true;
    }

    function unfreeze(uint256 _value) whenNotPaused public returns (bool) {
        require(_value <= freezes[msg.sender]);

        freezes[msg.sender] = freezes[msg.sender].sub(_value);
        balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].add(_value);
        emit Unfreeze(msg.sender, _value);
        return true;
    }

    /**
    * @dev Allows the current owner to transfer control of the contract to a newOwner.
    * @param newOwner The address to transfer ownership to.
    */
    function transferOwnership(address newOwner) onlyOwner whenNotPaused public {
        super.transferOwnership(newOwner);
    }

    /**
    * The fallback function.
    */
    function() payable external {
        revert();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you need more information let me know.

Comment: can you provide you current attempts? I mean you contract

Comment: Without more details from your contract (like the name of variables used) is hard to say something useful. For example if you use OpenZeppelin contracts you need something like `_mint(0xAAAAA..A, INITIAL_SUPPLY/2); _mint(0xBBBBB..B, INITIAL_SUPPLY/2)`.

Comment: Seems like a hard problem or does it need more information ? 500000000 is my custom ERC20 Token total and I want to split them between 3 accounts. for example 0xAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA = 200000000 0xBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB = 200000000 0xCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC = 100000000 means 3 ethereum accounts

Answer (score 0):

From the question it is not clear what is required.

Following is a very basic `contract` that requires `1 ether` to deploy. Then splits  that ether between `2 addresses` evenly upon calling `allocate` by the owner.

```
pragma solidity >=0.5.4 <0.6.0;

contract SplitSupply {
    address owner;
    address payable private team = 0x14723A09ACff6D2A60DcdF7aA4AFf308FDDC160C;
    address payable private crowd = 0x4B0897b0513fdC7C541B6d9D7E929C4e5364D2dB;

    constructor() payable public {
        require(1 ether < msg.value);
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function allocate() public {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        address(team).transfer(address(this).balance / 2);
        address(crowd).transfer(address(this).balance);
    }
}
```

Comment: It’s a Token, I’ve edit my question

Comment: not really what i'm looking for

Comment: Let's start over again. You want to deploy such a contract that will receive some `value` in `constructor`. You save that in `totalSupply_`. Then it get a bit fuzzy for me. Do you want to send `half` of `totalSupply_` to `an account` and other half to another account?

Comment: Hey Thanks for your reply, correct but I want to display the token amounts in numbers 
like in my case 250000000 * (10 ** uint256(decimals)) and not /2
send to two separate addresses

Comment: Is that something where you can help ?

Comment: Is `500000000` your token amount and not ether? If it is indeed ether do you want to transfer half of to 2 accounts?

Comment: right its not ether, its an ERC20 Token and I want to initial transfer to two or more addresses. 
thats why /2 is not an option and i need a full value or something like 
uint256 public constant amount1 = 250000000 
totalSupply_ +=amount1 

or something similar

Comment: What is idea behind writting `totalSupply_ = 500000000 * (10 ** uint256(decimals));`?

Comment: the decimals, this is common standard. Hope you can help me with my problem, I even didn’t found anything on google

Comment: Is `500000000` your own `custom Token` total and you want to split them between `2 accounts`? In your example does `0xAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA` and `0xBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB` mean `2 ethereum accounts`? If it is indeed true then you simply can't allocate anything to these accounts. **ethereum accounts** can only hold **ether** not some other custom `ERC20` token.

Comment: Can’t, be true. Ethereum Adresses can hold ERC20 Token and I can transfer them

Answer (score 0):

In the constructor, just replace the line that says

```js
balances[msg.sender] = totalSupply
```

with something like

```js
balances[0xA] = 250000000 * 10 ** 18;
balances[0xB] = 250000000 * 10 ** 18;
```

(where `0xA` and `0xB` are your 2 hardcoded addresses).

That way on deployment, both 0xA and 0xB start with 250 million.

By the way, you can also write

```js
balances[0xA] = 250000000 ether;
balances[0xB] = 250000000 ether;
```

it's equivalent